# Tooltip in swing

Tags: java, html, swing, scrollbar, tooltip

I made to tool tip for comportment in swing using some html tags

```
_graph.setToolTipText("<html><div style=\"width: 300px; height: 100px;" 
   +  " overflow: auto; border: 0;<p style=\"padding:2 5 2 5;\"></div>Please Wait...");
```

Here  `_graph` is object of  component. Problem is, if data is exceeds I need to scroll but it is not happening.please anyone suggest me to make scrollbar.

Comment: Are you asking for a tooltip containing a scrollbar ? Looking at your tooltip-text (Please Wait...) are you sure you are talking about a tooltip, which is by defenition "a small "hover box" with information about the item being hovered over"

Comment: @Robn Yes , im talking  about tooltip with scrollbar

Comment: Your question is more like Russian and not clear. Please respect the [sscce](http://sscce.org)

Comment: why do you need scrollbar if you are just writing **Please Wait..**?

Comment: that's not supported by default. You can implement a custom JToolTip and implement your graph component to return the custom tooltip in createTooltip

Answer (score 7):

Default tooltips are very basic: simply a lable-like component, even limited to text-only (except html). As I already mentioned, the way to more fancy tooltips is to extend JTooltip and let your graph component return that custom tooltip in createTooltip. An [example and some pitfalls](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2128796) were recently discussed over at OTN

Answer (score 2):

I do not know how to create a tooltip containing a scrollbar, but I can think of several reasons why you should reconsider whether you want this.

1. I do not know any application which has a tooltip containing a scrollbar, so no user is going to expect that.
2. A tooltip is by definition a small "hover box" with information about the item being hovered over. How do you combine small with the fact you need a scrollbar in it ?
3. Have you encountered a tooltip where you could click on some text and which would show more information ? How many times did you had to try with your mouse to navigate to the link, without having the tooltip to disappear ? That is not user-friendly. A scrollbar will have the  same problem.

So my advise: rethink your UI design. Judging from the text of your tooltip in the question, I would guess you need some sort of overlay displaying a "Please wait" message.

Comment: "Inspect" during debug in Eclipse is very similar to tool-tips and have scroll bars (both vertical and horizontal) and complex tree that requires many actions from user.

Comment: 1., 3. yes, Eclipse popup javadoc :-) Tooltips get richer and Swing's way to try coping is html. So far everything's okay with the OPs solution. Though from the example I don't understand the problem completely, either ;-)

Comment: IntelliJ has that as well, but it is not a real tooltip (For example to display javadoc, but I can move that "tooltip"). It is more like a new window which I can invoke with a keyboard shortcut and appears next to my mouse cursor. It also requires one mouse-click or ESC-key press to disappear again. I will check at home with Eclipse or search for a screenshot to see what you mean, and whether I find it user friendly. For the moment I stick to my advise though

Comment: @Adel Boutrous Im getting data from database .I need to put that text in tooltip just i give example their data will change dynamically

Comment: why overflow: auto is not working in            _graph.setToolTipText("<html><div style=\"width: 300px; height: 100px;" 
   +  " overflow: auto; border: 0;<p style=\"padding:2 5 2 5;\"></div>Please Wait...");  With and height are working